# Automake: set data file permission pattern

Tags: build, permissions, installation, gnu, automake

I know I can use `install-data-hook` to do anything I want after my data files are copied and, this way, I can adjust the file permissions the way I want.

My question, though, becomes before it.

Is there any way I can tell `automake` to set a standard permission mask for any data group *before* it gets copied?

I mean I want the resulting `install` to do its task using the correct mask rather than letting it to use the standard `0644` and after it correct all the file permissions.

In other words, I want the task do get done right at first and not having to fix it later.

Is is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automake implements the [GNU Standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html). These state that data files should be installed using the command `$(INSTALL_DATA)`,  [which should default to `$(INSTALL) -m 644`](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command-Variables).

What you can do is overwrite the value of `INSTALL_DATA` in some `Makefile.am`, then *all* data files installed by this `Makefile.am` will use that definition.  If you have two groups of data files that require different modes, you will have to move them in two different directories so they can have their own `Makefile`.

Comment: How do you set `INSTALL_DATA` in `Makefile.am`? If I try `INSTALL_DATA = $(INSTALL) -m 600`, I get an error `'INSTALL_DATA' is used but 'INSTALLdir' is undefined`.

Comment: Do you know how to overwrite `INSTALL_DATA` as you suggested? Can it be done in `Makefile.am`—and if so what's the syntax—or does it have to be done in another file?

Comment: You can certainly override it from `configure.ac` using `AC_SUBST` (but that is global to all makefiles).  I don't see any strong reason why overriding it from `Makefile.am` should be disallowed; I suggest you file this as a bug.

Comment: I think the reason is that automake identifies `INSTALL_DATA` as a ["special" variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Uniform.html), similar to patterns such as `bin_PROGRAMS` and `sysconf_DATA`. How can we change `INSTALL_DATA` in `Makefile.am` without automake thinking it's a "special" variable?

Comment: Automake itself is reading the definition of `INSTALL_DATA` from some automake-supplied Makefile template, and it has specific handling code to *not* interpret `INSTALL_DATA` as a special variable.  However this code will only work when reading the automake-supplied templates, and not when reading the user-supplied `Makefile.am` (your case).   That's why I think you should report it as a bug to the Automake developpers (bug-automake@gnu.org).